# errors STL export, contains rotate or GeometricTransformation

Tags: export, version-9

I failed  to export a STL file containing a Graphics3D with a Rotate or GeometricTransformation.

```
poly1 = N@Normal@PolyhedronData["RhombicHexecontahedron", "Edges"];

poly2 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], Table[Tube[poly1[[1, i]], 0.1], {i, 1, Length[poly1[[1]]]}]}];

vertex = N@Normal@PolyhedronData["RhombicHexecontahedron", "Edges"][[1]];

poly3 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], Sphere[vertex, 0.1]}];

polyedge = Show[{poly2, poly3}]

Export["success.stl", polyedge]
```

then, success stl export!!

But,

```
gf = Graphics3D@GeometricTransformation[polyedge[[1]], RotationTransform[1, {1, 0, 0}]]

gf = Graphics3D@Rotate[polyedge[[1]], 1, {1, 0, 0}]

Export["fail.stl", gf]
```

then failed stl export!!

i know the reason.because "Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the STL format.

i want other way ...your opinions?

thanks you. your answer.

Comment: i use Mathematica version 9

Comment: If you have the opportunity to upgrade, [version 10.2 has significantly improved STL import/export](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html).